# Find form owner based off formkey

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking for a way to determine who the owner of a form is based off the url or formkey.  The drive api needs a document id, which doesn't appear related to formkey.

For example, I only have access to a url like:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/domain.com/viewform?hl=en&formkey=cE5qcHk3VzVtUTduaTBWWmtXVjdIV0E6M

Answer (score 0):

`formkey` is idential to the `fileId`, you can use it on the permissions resource to retrieve the permissions of the spreadsheet.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<formKey>/permissions
```

Comment: Where's the source of this URL?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1krrtJH-yG-4t_ki880cmKtplaTlhJ-d3HIdLagwCqqY/viewform

Comment: This won't work unless you authorize as the document's owner which would again require an attempt with each user in the domain until the right one is found.